# Install MSI in VSTS Release

Tags: azure-devops, windows-installer, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We package our software to **MSI** files (using Wix).
We use **VSTS** for Builds and Releases.

Is there a standard way to **deploy MSI file as part of the Release**?

Yes, I can run `msiexec /i ...` as PowerShell or batch script. But we would need a few other things, for example checking exit code, uploading install log file back to VSTS Release or analysing error message, etc.

This all sounds like quite common thing people would like to do, but there is no such standard VSTS step \ extension for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up packaging VSTS extension for this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ivanboyko.vsts-deploy-MSI

Source code is open-sourced:
https://github.com/IvanBoyko/vsts-install-MSI.git

[image: Adding step from Task catalog to Install MSI file]

Comment: Looks like your extension disappeared from the marketplace, was this intentional?

Comment: I didn't have time to maintain it, so they removed it after it became incompatible with some rules like Category or something. I don't work with VSTS anymore, so couldn't justify spending time on this. Source code is open source, so you can take and package it as yours own VSTS extension if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify log file in msiexec command to install MSI file, then check the detail log content (whether contains errors) by using PowerShell, if there are errors in the log, you can log error or warning by using **##vso[task.logissue].**

Regarding upload log file, you can use **##vso[build.uploadlog]local file path** to upload installer log file.
More information about logging commands, you can refer to this article: [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

Simple code to install MSI and **wait for the installer to finish**:

```
$filePath='[msi file path]'
$DataStamp = get-date -Format yyyyMMddTHHmmss                
$logFile = 'c:\{0}-{1}.log' -f 'nodejsInstall',$DataStamp                
$MSIArguments = @(
    "/i"
    ('"{0}"' -f $filePath)
    "/qn"
    "/norestart"
    "/L*v"
    $logFile
)               
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $MSIArguments -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've already made a script that does this, including **task.logissue** and **task.uploadlog**. My question was if there was a **standard** approach for such common task as installing MSI in VSTS Release - something like a build step. Custom script is difficult to scale - to apply it in dozens of projects I manage.